# what is the probability that there are at least two people with this type of blood in that group of 3000 people?

Tags: probability

A certain rare blood type is in only $0.05$% of people. If $3000$ people are randomly selected, what is the probability that there are at least two people with this type of blood in that group of $3000$ people?

**My work**

Let $X=$ People selected. Then $X=1,2,3,...,3000.$

I'm going to use a Binomial distribution.

Let $p$ a probability function, then
 $P(X\geq 2)=1-P(X<2)=1-\binom {3000} {1}(0,05)^1(1-0,05)^{3000-1}=1$

But i don't know. I think the exercise is bad, can someone help me?

**Note:** Only can be solved using, Bernoulli, Binomial, Poisson, Uniform discrete distribution. Thanks for all

Comment: Although a Binomial distribution is correct, a Poisson distribution is also appropriate here and may result in an easier computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to subtract off the case where 0 people have that blood type:
$$P(X \geq 2) = 1-P(X = 1)-P(X = 0)$$
Otherwise, your approach seems totally correct. The probability should be very close to 1, since 5% of 3000 is 150, which is the expected number of people with the blood type. Is it possible that the exercise reads 0.05%? This would provide a probability that is not essentially 1.

Comment: yes, is $0.05$% in that case What would it change?

Comment: @Bvss12: $0.05$% is equal to $0.0005$.  You should replace all occurrences of $0.05$ in your formula above in the original post with $0.0005$.

Comment: OH YEAH, TRUE. Thanks @BrianTung